# Programmaticaly get all users/groups with permission on item

Tags: 2013, permissions, item

I need to get all users/groups that have permissions on an item x, is there any way to get this information via C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. You can use CSOM. Connect to web using credentials, get list that you want. Get all items or specific field using caml query

```
query.ViewXml = "<View/>";
items=SourceList.GetItems(query);
clientContext1.Load(items);
clientContext1.ExecuteQuery();
```

Each item like SecurableObject has it's permissions list.

- item.RoleAssignments; - it is permissions list
- each permission has:
- permission.RoleDefinitionBindings
- permission.Member

Comment: Could use fleshing out a bit...